# Pandas select row based on user input of column names and values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, user-input

I have a dataframe with many columns.
I would like to select the row  based on user input for the four variables below

- column 1 selected (user can select any column),
- value 1 selected  (user can select any value in column 1),
- column 2 selected (user can select any column),
- value 2 selected  (user can select any value in column 2),

How do I solved this using pandas?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try this,

```
# given col1, val1, col2, val2
result_rows = df[(df[col1] == val1) & (df[col2] == val2)]
```

you can take a look at how to select data in pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html